# Start google chrome in the background in Gnome - do not focus on the window

Tags: google-chrome, gnome, window

I am running Linux Mint - Debian edition (with Gnome2) on my HTPC with Boxee on top. Boxee is set to start automatically at login in Gnome2 and that works fine, but I am also looking to start Chrome after login - or a Chrome app - somewhere in the background in case I want to do other things besides using Boxee. The problem with this is that Chrome steals the focus from Boxee when it starts.

I know that Chrome has a "-start-maximized" flag, but do you know of any way to make it start minimized, or in the background or just tell it not to steal focus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latest version of Chrome also has a parameter to run in background.

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window
```

This works fine for me in Ubuntu 11.10 with Google Chrome 15.0.874.106.

There's an option in Chrome's preferences to do that. In wrench menu, under the hood section, there's **"Background Apps, Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"** checkbox.

In Windows I even have a system tray icon when I enable this option, but in Ubuntu I couldn't get one, but still it works in the background (also it starts in every session automatically).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps. I did manage to do this with Devil's Pie but it would be a lot nicer to do it without an external program.

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to do it using [Devil's Pie](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-start-applications-minimized.html). It can be installed using `sudo apt-get install devilspie`

I just matched the google chrome window using the string "Google Chrome".